# Are there reasons why huge sites Walmart, Amazaon, Ticketmaster, Verizon etc.. do not include contentSecurityPolicy?

Tags: nginx, http-headers, response-headers, helmet.js

So, I've been inspecting the headers of these big websites that do a LOT of excommerce, but I don't see very many secure headers that would denote high security.... most notable, contentSecurityPolicy.. why do they not include it?

So I went to these websites and no: Content-Security-Policy
Note: I'm trying to get it going on my website, and its turning into a HUGE pain in the arse, especially with googletagmanager etc....

netflix, amazon, ticketmaster, verizon, walmart etc..

Comment: I can't speak to the technical decisionmaking of anyone else, but I've often eschewed CSP because (1) it is often considered defense-in-depth—you should be sanitizing your inputs whether you have a CSP or not (2) it isn't perfectly supported on all browsers (3) it's a lot of work.

Comment: I'm finding that it is a LOT of work...